# How can I put my WAMP online only for some projects

Tags: ip, wampserver

Is there a way to choose the projects that will be accessible from **Wamp** online

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I edited the **www/inde.php** file

```
$projectsListToShow = array('myProjects');
```

.

```
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{
    if (is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$projectsListIgnore)
        && in_array($file,$projectsListToShow))
    {       
        $projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```